# Convert data to json format with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

Long story short, i have the following code which is gettin info about an order from api in json, and should send this order to another system through api. All steps works good, but my problem it's if i have more products on order, my script it's creating a new order for each one.

SCRIPT:

```
    foreach($data['orders'] as $key => $val)
    {
        $phone = $val['phone'];
        $email = $val['email'];
        $fullname = $val['invoice_fullname'];    
        $invoicecompany = $val['invoice_company'];
        $invoicenip = $val['invoice_nip'];
        $invoiceaddress = $val['invoice_address'];
        $invoicecity = $val['invoice_city'];
        $deliveryprice = $val['delivery_price'];
        $deliverymethod = $val['delivery_method'];
    }
    
    foreach($data['orders'][0]['products'] as $key => $val){
        $pidBl = $val['product_id'];
        $ean = $val['ean'];
        $grossprice = $val['price_brutto'];
        $vatrate = $val['tax_rate'];
        $quantity = $val['quantity'];
    
    
    
    //open db
    $dbc = mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    $dbSelected = mysqli_select_db($dbc , $database);
    $q = $dbc->query("SELECT pId FROM offers WHERE pBarcode = '$ean';");
    
    while ($rs = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pId = $rs['pId'];
    
    
    }
    $arr = [
            "objects" => [],
            "returnColumns" => []
    
        ];
    $arr['objects'][] = [
    "name" => $fullname,
    "uniqueCode" => $invoicenip,
    "active" => "true"
    ];
    $arr['returnColumns'][] = ["name" => "id"];
    
    
    
    $preparesedona = json_encode($arr);
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'BLABLABLA',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $preparesedona,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'accept: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic BLABLABLA',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    
    
    foreach($data['result'] as $key => $val){
    $customerId = $val['id'];
    }
    
    
    
    $arr = [
            "objects" => [],
            "returnColumns" => []
    
        ];
    
    
    $arr['objects'][] = [
    "client_id" => $customerId,
    "user_id" => 1,
    "administration_id" => 1,
    "status" => 1,
    "deliveryType" => 1,
    "details" => []
    ];
    
    $arr['objects'][0]['details'][] =  [
    
    "product_id" => $pId,
    "unitPriceWithVat" => $grossprice,
    "orderedUnits" => $quantity
    
    ];
    
    $arr['returnColumns'][] = ["name" => "id"];
    
    
    $preparesedona = json_encode($arr);
    
    
     $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'BLABLABLA',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $preparesedona,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'accept: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic BLABLABLA',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
    
    }
```

Yas, i know that somewhere it's a small thing which is making difference, but trust me, i tried in any possible way, i tried to look on similar errors and problems but i cannot find anything related cause i have multiple arrays which should be defined and filled...

This is how it looks my postfields

```
{
   "objects":[
      {
         "client_id":21947,
         "user_id":1,
         "administration_id":1,
         "status":1,
         "deliveryType":1,
         "details":[
            {
               "product_id":"11407",
               "unitPriceWithVat":159.7,
               "orderedUnits":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "returnColumns":[
      {
         "name":"id"
      }
   ]
}{
   "objects":[
      {
         "client_id":21948,
         "user_id":1,
         "administration_id":1,
         "status":1,
         "deliveryType":1,
         "details":[
            {
               "product_id":"14575",
               "unitPriceWithVat":45.31,
               "orderedUnits":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "returnColumns":[
      {
         "name":"id"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is how should look like:

```
{
   "objects":[
      {
         "client_id":21947,
         "user_id":1,
         "administration_id":1,
         "status":1,
         "deliveryType":1,
         "details":[
            {
               "product_id":"11407",
               "unitPriceWithVat":159.7,
               "orderedUnits":1
            },
            {
               "product_id":"14575",
               "unitPriceWithVat":45.31,
               "orderedUnits":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "returnColumns":[
      {
         "name":"id"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would much appreciate your help and please, be sympathetic, i'm not a pro, i just try to learn and i promise that i do my best :)

Comment: Given that both orders have a different `client_id` value, why do you want to merge them?

Comment: HI Nick, my bad, mb i didn't explain very well, i need to be created just one customer, but  yesterday i was very tired and i was blind for simplest solution... fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, baiscally, i make one call to API1 to get general info about order and creating customer in API2 // after that i made another call to API1 to get info about products and this is how i structured my script and it's workin very well.

```
// gettin info about order data
foreach($data['orders'] as $key => $val)
{
    $phone = $val['phone'];
    $email = $val['email'];
    $fullname = $val['invoice_fullname'];    
    $invoicecompany = $val['invoice_company'];
    $invoicenip = $val['invoice_nip'];
    $invoiceaddress = $val['invoice_address'];
    $invoicecity = $val['invoice_city'];
    $deliveryprice = $val['delivery_price'];
    $deliverymethod = $val['delivery_method'];
    $deliveryaddress = $val ['delivery_address'];

// CREATE CUSTOMER -------------------------


$arr = [
        "objects" => [],
        "returnColumns" => []

    ];
$arr['objects'][] = [
"name" => $fullname,
"uniqueCode" => $invoicenip,
"active" => "true"
];
$arr['returnColumns'][] = ["name" => "id"];



$preparesedona = json_encode($arr);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'BLABLABLABLA',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $preparesedona,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic BLABLABLABLA',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

$customerId = $data['result'][0]['id'];

}
// Call again to get data for products

 $methodParams = [
    'order_id' => $orderidbl
];

$apiParams = [
    'method'     => 'getOrders',
    'parameters' => json_encode($methodParams),
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["X-BLToken: BLABLABLABLA-BLABLABLABLA-BLABLABLABLA"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiParams));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($output, true);


$arr = [
        "objects" => [],
        "returnColumns" => []

       ];

$arr['objects'][] = [
"client_id" => $customerId,
"user_id" => 1,
"administration_id" => 1,
"status" => 1,
"deliveryType" => 1,
"deliveryAddress" => $deliveryaddress,
"details" => []
];

$arr['returnColumns'][] = ["name" => "id"];

// prepare products area "details"

foreach($data['orders'][0]['products'] as $key => $val){
    $pidBl = $val['product_id'];
    $ean = $val['ean'];
    $grossprice = $val['price_brutto'];
    $vatrate = $val['tax_rate'];
    $quantity = $val['quantity'];



//open db
$dbc = mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
$dbSelected = mysqli_select_db($dbc , $database);
$q = $dbc->query("SELECT pId FROM offers WHERE pBarcode = '$ean';");

while ($rs = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pId = $rs['pId'];
}


$arr['objects'][0]['details'][] =  [

"product_id" => $pId,
"unitPriceWithVat" => $grossprice,
"orderedUnits" => $quantity

];
}

$preparesedona = json_encode($arr);

var_dump($preparesedona);
```